# Is it safe to use Mojave's Boot Camp Assistant to remove a Windows 7 partition?

Tags: windows, bootcamp, mojave, partition

I have a Windows 7 Boot Camp partition that I want to remove. It was set up in Boot Camp in earlier versions of MacOS; however, I have since updated to Mojave and it seems that Boot Camp Assistant has updated, too. Its partition removal option only mentions "Remove Windows 10 or later version", suggesting it might not support removing earlier versions. Can that option still be used to safely remove the partition or should it be avoided?

**Edit:** per @Jean_JD's follow-up question, the results of running the `diskutil list internal` command:

```
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *500.3 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk1         401.1 GB   disk0s2
   3:       Microsoft Basic Data BOOTCAMP                99.0 GB    disk0s3

/dev/disk1 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +401.1 GB   disk1
                                 Physical Store disk0s2
   1:                APFS Volume Macintosh HD            378.3 GB   disk1s1
   2:                APFS Volume Preboot                 113.3 MB   disk1s2
   3:                APFS Volume Recovery                2.1 GB     disk1s3
   4:                APFS Volume VM                      1.1 GB     disk1s4
```

Comment: It's possible suppress BootCamp partition manually. Can you give the results (text) of the terminal command `diskutil list internal` ?

Comment: @Jean_JD Sure - the output is too long to reply to here, so I've added it to my original question.

Answer (score 1):

Ok. Execute the terminal command :

```
diskutil erasevolume free space disk0s3
```

Then, I suppose you want add the free space to your Mac os x Container.
If yes, execute :

```
diskutil ap resizecontainer disk1 0b
```

Then, to suppress Windows references at boot, you mount the EFI partition :

```
sudo diskutil mount disk0s1
```

Your password will be requiered and don't show up when you type it

Then you give the results of :

```
ls -l /Volumes/EFI/EFI
```

Normaly you have a Directory WINDOWS, so you delete it :

```
rm -r /Volumes/EFI/EFI/WINDOWS
```

And it's all ;-)

Comment: The installation of Windows would not create the folder `/Volumes/EFI/EFI/WINDOWS`. If Windows was installed to UEFI boot, then you would you would want to remove the `/Volumes/EFI/EFI/Boot` and `/Volumes/EFI/EFI/Microsoft`. However, Windows 7 can only be installed to BIOS boot on Mac computers. So here would be nothing to remove from the EFI volume.

Comment: Also, I would think you would want to finish with a `diskutil unmount disk0s1`.

Comment: @DavidAnderson Does that mean I would only need to use the first two commands in Jean_JD's answer? Would that be sufficient to ensure the Windows partition is no available as a boot option?

Comment: There is no problem to try the 2 first commands and test is at boot you don't have Windows option.

Comment: @James: I would know if the first two commands would work properly only if I first saw the output from the command `fdisk /dev/disk0`. This command would have to be entered while booted to macOS Recovery. The command does not change your Mac. The command only shows the contents of the MBR partition table.

Comment: @James: However, if you did enter the first two commands and something went wrong. The new problem could be fixed.

Comment: @Jean_JD: The `diskutil erasevolume free space disk0s3` command  will look at the partition type id for the APFS partition in the MBR partition table. If the id is `00`, `07` or `FF`, then the  command will work correctly. If the id is `AF`, then the partition type GUID in the GPT for the APFS partition will change to `48465300-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC` (which is Apple_HFS). If the id is `DA` then the partition type GUID in the GPT for the APFS partition will change to `FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFFFF`. I did not test for the other 251 possible id values.